# What is the time complexity of forEach?

Tags: javascript, big-o

What is the time complexity of forEach function? O(n+n*m) or O(n+n*n)? There one loop and then nested loop. I will be grateful if you explain

```js
function size(n) {
  let counter = 0

  while (counter !== n) {
    counter++;
  }

  return counter;
}

function getAt(index) {
  let counter = 0;
  while (counter !== index) {
    counter++;
  }
  return counter;
}

function forEach(fn) {
  const size = size(3);

  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    fn(getAt(i), i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends on the callback passed to forEach

Answer (score 1):

This would be n^2, because you have a loop that will iterate `i` times being called from inside of a loop that iterates `size` times.

Comment: Nope, size(3) is constant (3). ```i``` is not a parameter of forEach. The runtime only depends on the passed fn. O(forEach) = O(3 * fn) => O(forEach) = O(fn).

Comment: While size(3) will always be 3, I was considering that `3` to be `n` in this case and assuming that it being hard coded was just bad practice on the part of OP. If we do not make that assumption then this runs in constant time.